# Delete Model object in django Using jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, python-2.7

Having a hard time deleting an object using jquery/ajax. I have implemented a table that has rows containing a list of objects from Appointment model. There is a delete button in each row.

**Template for objects' table is :**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-list">
    <thead>
     <tr>
        <th><em class="fa fa-cog"></em></th>
        <th class="hidden-xs">ID</th>
        <th>Patient Name</th>
        <th>Day</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Location</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for appointment in appointments %}
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <button class="delete_button" id="{{ appointment.id }}">
                        <em class="fa fa-trash"></em>
                    </button>
                </td>
                  <td>1</td>
                <td class="hidden" id="appointment_id">{{ appointment.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ appointment.patient }}</td>
                <td>{{ appointment.day }}</td>
                <td>{{ appointment.time }}</td>
                <td>{% if appointment.clinic %}
                      {{ appointment.clinic }}
                      {% endif %}
                      {% if appointment.hospital %}
                      {{ appointment.hospital }}
                      {% endif %}
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Javascript is as below :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".delete_button").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: "{% url 'deleteappointment' %}",
            data: { 'id' : id },
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", {% csrf_token %} );
            },
            success: function(response){
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Nothing is happening when I click on the delete button. What am I doing wrong here ?

**EDIT 2**
 **This is going on in ajax request :**
Syntaxerror in console :

```
beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='LUgmNbcWfkIR9KpLi7lzsn0QOk' /> );
                },
```

How do I prevent csrftoken tag to render the whole input field here ?

Comment: any error in console??

Comment: I'd imagine its because you don't declare its a post request but hard to say without more info, if it is then use `$.post` instead of `$.ajax`

Comment: @Manu uncaughtsyntax error in csrf token header.
django's {% csrf_token %} is giving an input field in the header.

Comment: Found Error in header : 
The header is looking like this :
beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='LUgmNbcWfkIR9KpLi7lzsn0QOkREPZmxABWf' /> );
                },

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using the `{% csrf_token %}` template tag which inserts the token in a html format for a form. You can use the other type of brackets (inside quotes)

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", {% csrf_token %} );
```

should be

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", "{{ csrf_token }}");
```

Comment: Already did this. Now getting this :

"Uncaught ReferenceError : l3ts9IEg7JfopQmeb0xiGq5AgPoHFVLjaK.. is not defined."
The random string is the csrf token.

Comment: Did you forget the quotes around the tag?... Although this is verging into a separate issue..

Comment: Replacing {% csrf_token %} with "{{ csrf_token }}" worked like a charm!